# Exact banner image size for mobile responsive for different device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

How to handle Banner image responsive for different devices like small and medium mobile and tablet.?

Comment: Use media queries to resize them according to your needs.

Comment: use media queries or use bootstrap for making  responsive website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Width:

```
.banner
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

> 2. Media Query:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
        .banner
        {
          width: 960px
          height: auto;
        }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
        .banner
        {
          width: 1440px
          height: auto;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        .banner
        {
          width: 2000px
          height: auto;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
       .banner
        {
          width: 480px
          height: auto;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
       .banner
        {
          width: 768px
          height: auto;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap framework. add img-responsive class to image

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image" >
```

Comment: @ArumugamG it's better to use bootstrap if you want full responsive website

Comment: sure @Syam lal will do the same, can you suggest some reference learning site  for developing a responsive website

Answer (score 0):

It also depeds on your image, does the main content of your image occupies all the space?, is there anything you can cut? if that's the case, you can achieve it with object-fit, object-position, and the width and height will not vary too much.
If you can modify by yourself the image, use the img srcset property, where you designate which image should be displayed in different resolution breakpoints.
If none of previous options suits you, try with vmax, you'll have fun guessing the right measures, but once that it's done, you won't need too much media queries
Finally, there's the tedious way, setting various media queries.